# Issue running a simple login app

Tags: android, android-layout

I was learning to make a simple login app from youtube, however, when I build the code, although the app runs quite fine but it never assigns the value of 3 to the attempt counter later in the code, only the layout is visible and hence login doesn't work. Can you please help me? If you need any other file, write it in comment, I'll upload it later. Thanks.

```
package com.shubham.splashscreenemulation;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class UserLogin extends AppCompatActivity  {

private static EditText username;
private static EditText password;
private static TextView attempts_left;
private static Button login_btn;
int attempt_counter = 3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_login);
}

public void LoginButton(){

    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_user);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
    attempts_left = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_attempt_count);
    login_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_login);

    attempts_left.setText(Integer.toString(attempt_counter));

    login_btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){

                    if(username.getText().toString().equals("Shubh") && password.getText().toString().equals("adidev"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, "Login credentials are correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.shubham.splashscreenemulation.SplashScreen");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, "Login credentials are not correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        attempt_counter--;
                        attempts_left.setText(Integer.toString(attempt_counter));
                        if(attempt_counter == 0)
                        {
                            login_btn.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                }


            }

    );
}


 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't call the function LoginButton() in your Activity.

Here some tips : function name starts with lowercase letter like loginButton ( with camelCase ), classes names starts with uppercase letter like AppCompatActivity. This tip is for more readability for the code. Why do you declare Views as static in that function?

```
package com.shubham.splashscreenemulation;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class UserLogin extends AppCompatActivity  {

private static EditText username;
private static EditText password;
private static TextView attempts_left;
private static Button login_btn;
int attempt_counter = 3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_login);
    LoginButton();

}

public void LoginButton(){

    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_user);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
    attempts_left = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_attempt_count);
    login_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_login);

    attempts_left.setText(Integer.toString(attempt_counter));

    login_btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){

                    if(username.getText().toString().equals("Shubh") && password.getText().toString().equals("adidev"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, "Login credentials are correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.shubham.splashscreenemulation.SplashScreen");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, "Login credentials are not correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        attempt_counter--;
                        attempts_left.setText(Integer.toString(attempt_counter));
                        if(attempt_counter == 0)
                        {
                            login_btn.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                }


            }

    );
}
```

Comment: can u elaborate

Comment: Is it your first Android Project? If so you should follow some course ( Udacity for example, is free and good ) which is gonna help you get into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `LoginButton()` after `setContentView` or remove the LoginButton method, move everything inside onCreate.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_login);
        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_user);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
        attempts_left = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_attempt_count);
        login_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        attempts_left.setText(Integer.toString(attempt_counter));
        login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
              public void onClick(View v){
                 if(username.getText().toString().equals("Shubh") && password.getText().toString().equals("adidev"))
                  {
                     Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, "Login credentials are correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     Intent intent = new Intent("com.shubham.splashscreenemulation.SplashScreen");
                     startActivity(intent);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, "Login credentials are not correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      attempt_counter--;                        attempts_left.setText(Integer.toString(attempt_counter));
                      if(attempt_counter == 0)
                       {
                           login_btn.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                   }
                 }   
              });
            }
```

You can also change your setText to this  `attempts_left.setText(attempt_counter+"");`

Comment: thank u very much but might I ask why did it not work that way?

Comment: Because you are not declaring the `LoginButton` method inside the `onCreate`. Add it inside `onCreate` method like @sgrumo said, then it will work.